# How to make discord embed pages that can be browsed? (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that can add to a database and then the info is extracted from database and sent in an embed. So, I tried to make embed pages, example if 10 entries are made in the database, it automatically creates a page 2 that can be accessed using buttons.
I tried using for loop like this:

```
pages = (entries // 10) + 1
for i in range(pages):
  embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Page {i+1}")
  db[f"pagesembed_{i+1}"]=embed
```

But I got a JSON decode error, so I decided to convert the embed value to string like this:

```
embed=str(discord.Embed(title=f"Page {i+1}"))
```

Then when I try to load into a message, it gives me `Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`

I don't know what to do, I have contemplated using SQLite for storing the page embeds, maybe that should work but I need to ask if there is another way of doing it, I would really appreciate if someone would help! Thank you.

Comment: You can't store arbitrary objects in your database... Have a look at https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus

Comment: Embed objects have a `to_dict` method. Dicts can be stringified as JSON, so there you have a string...

Comment: Otherwise just store the titles (and other content you need) in separate columns. And you build the embed from that

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the embed class with pickle and than load it from the database

save example:

```py
import pickle
import discord

exampleEmbedToSave = discord.Embed(title="example", description="example")
db["embed"] = pickle.dumps(exampleEmbedToSave) # the function pickle.dumps will dump the class into a string
```

Load example:

```py
import pickle
import discord

loadedEmbed = pickle.loads(db["embed"]) # pickle.loads is used to load the class from the string

# >> In a command:
await channel.send(embed=loadedEmbed)
```